# Chainer trainerからの重みパラメータ取り出し

Tags: python, chainer

Chainerでは通常、`model.predictor.conv2.W.data` などとしてネットワークのパラメータを取り出せると思います。(model:＜class 'chainer.links.model.classifier.Classifier'＞)

途中経過のパラメータも保存したいと思い、リジュームの実装でよく使われるTrainerの `extension.snapshot()` を使ったのですが、保存されるスナップショットは`<class 'chainer.training.trainer.Trainer'>` となり、パラメータの取り出し方がわかりません。

```
$ zipinfo snapshot_xxxxxx
-rw-------  2.0 unx  2457680 b- defN 17-Jul-27 11:17 updater/optimizer:main/predictor/l1/W/m.npy
```

で重みが入っていることは確認できています。
イメージとしては `trainer.updater.optimizer.xxxx` で取り出せると思ったのですが。

いろいろ調べてみましたが、分からず質問させていただきました。
ヒントでも頂ければ幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: trainer.updater.get_optimizer('main').target でしょうか。試してませんが

Answer (score 0):

main/predictor/l1/W/m.npyにデータがあれば、そのデータをnumpy.savetextでテキストデータとして見えますけど、答えになってますか？
それか、trainerを使わず、for文でループ学習しながらserializers.save_npzでモデルを保存します。モデルは圧縮ファイルなので、解凍すれば中身に.npyファイルがあるので見えます。